# Start a Countdown timer in a Telerik RadGridView upon Button Click

Tags: gridview, timer, telerik, countdown

I have a Start Button as one of the RadGridView columns. Upon clicking it, I need to update another a Status Column value in that particular row with a value as started and another column as Time Remaining which should show a countdown Timer value (in minutes) decreasing and auto updates/refreshes its value **Every Minute**.

How can I achieve this? Also whenever I update the Status Column and assign the TimeRemaining timer value, is it possible to only update a particular row or shall all the rows be rebound?

Any help with suggestions or a sample solution would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Syed.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a timer in the event handler of the button column, and update the DataItem acordingly.
Also if the class you are binding implements INotifyPropertyChanged you don't need to rebind, it'll update automatically.

Comment: Being a newbie I would be glad if you could shoot a sample code on updating the DataItem. I am able to retrieve the SelectedItem but how do I assign the timer value back to the required column?